# NordVPN blocking Mongodb Atlas connection

Tags: vpn, mongodb

When I try to connect to Mongodb Atlas cluster, NordVPN blocks it (connecting via the Mongo shell). When I turn off Nord it is able to connect.

More Information:

- Database is on the cloud so it might be an issue related to that
- I am connecting to Mongodb via Mongoose
- Running Mongoose/Mongodb in a nodejs server with nodemon
- I have tried changing my dns addresses
- Nord is on the latest version (6.26.17.0)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

Following the docs here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#view-whitelist-entries

NordVPN's IP is blocked by mongodb, so I just needed to whitelist it. The IP changes based on the server so make sure to choose the same server every time if you're having the same issues as me :D

Comment: Are you sure its not the other way round